# Laravel 5.1 password reset email subject line

Tags: laravel, forgot-password, password-recovery

Is it possible to change the default subject of password reset email in Laravel 5.1? without editing the ResetsPasswords trait?, if yes, please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have find out the answer. We really don't need to override the ResetsPasswords trait. We can just add the subject line to the constructor of the PasswordController class: in

```
app\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController
```

in _construct function

```
 public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest');
    $this->subject = 'New Password Request'; // <-Password Reset Email Subject
}
```

Save and upload the file. That's it.